# QGIS 3.16.16 and Sharepoint

Tags: qgis, file-path, sharepoint

My company is transferring to using Sharepoint. Currently we are using a driver system.
We think we might run into the problem that paths to sources we use will be linked to our personal account of Sharepoint and it will make us unable to use eachothers QGis files.
For instance:
Via Sharepoint we will get path names like follows. C:\Users\**a.sanders**\*Company name*\*Team Name*\ - 1 Offertes

While currently we get the following path. N:\word\*Team Name*\7. Archeologie\1. Projecten\1. Moedermap\6. Veld\Meet

So with Sharepoint the bold text is my account name. If i link things under this name we fear my coworkers won't be able to work with the same files, since they wont get the same path as I do.

Does anyone have experience with working with QGis in combination with Sharepoint and multiple people using the same QGis projects? Is QGis ''smart'' enough to recognise that the account name will change but the rest of the path will lead to the same files?

Comment: I suggest you talk to your IT **now**. Because if you will have to store common data for the whole team on restricted paths, it wont be common data.

Comment: @Erik Yeah we voiced our concernes with our IT man. He thinks it might not be a problem if we move all our QGis data to Sharepoint. He thinks then the startingoff point for the filepaths will start after the account name and there won't be a problem then. But he doesn't know for certain, cause we are the only ones working in QGis. So every problem we run into is a first for him as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm currently going through similar things at a new job having come from working with normal file servers/network shares.

Firstly, QGIS/Sharepoint doesn't seem to have any trouble with the different paths (i.e. cloud location vs local cached copy on person Xs machine vs local cached copy on person Y's machine), at least when using the relative path option for the project.

What DOES seem to be an issue (I will need to investigate more) is that re-syncing will lead to loss of data. For example:

Person X opens a project with data in a database/files A. The latest info is synced to their local drive.
Person Y opens a project with data in database/files A. The latest info is synced to their local drive.

Person X does some edits and saves them and the project. Data is re-synced up to sharepoint.
Person Y does some edits (There is no notification of files in use/schema locking etc), saves them and saves the project. Data is re-synced up to sharepoint and person Xs data *is* either overwritten or a conflict copy is created (i.e. database A has its file name appended with person Xs machine name).

As I said, I need to investigate this more to confirm the exact behaviour but at first look, this seems to be the case.
I did some tests just with local features in a geopackage database and editing them from 2 different projects open at the same time. In that case, whoever did the last edit at the FEATURE level, had their edits saved but new features appeared.

The issue with sharepoint seems to be that it all happens at the FILE level....so if multiple edits are happening in a geopackage or sqlite etc then edits aren't resolved.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. We've found it works at this moment. But since we don't usually work in the same Qgis project at the same time we haven't had the issue you've discribed. It's good to know this is an issue though, before we try it out and have dataloss, so thank you for that info!

Comment: We have exactly the same ré-sync problem. @tim have you been able to resolve the issue?

Comment: We resolved it by moving to Postgis for centralized datasets and better ensuring only one person was working on any project at a time to resolve the geopackage issues.